# How to have PATCH field required in response but optional in request body?

Tags: php, openapi, api-platform.com

I have an entity with, among other fields :

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="float", name="shipping_fees")
 */
#[Groups(["stock:read", "stock:write"])]
#[Assert\PositiveOrZero]
#[Assert\NotNull]
private float $shippingFees = 0.;
```

And a `PATCH` request associated to this entity. The generated OpenAPI context marks `shippingFees` as a `required` property both in the `requestBody`, and in the response. (because of the `NotNull` constraint)

I expect the field to be optional in the request body, as this is a `PATCH` request. How can I achieve it ? And is this a malfunction of API Platform which I should report ?

Comment: If a developer parses my OpenAPI schemas, they will see that this field is required in the `PATCH` operation, which could lead to inconsistencies with, for instance, typescript, or auto-generated forms.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate serialization group just for the `PATCH` method, such as `stock:patch`. Then specify in the `Assert` annotations the serialization `groups` in which they should be applied. As shown below

```
  #[Groups(["stock:read", "stock:write", "stock:patch"])]
  #[Assert\PositiveOrZero]
  #[Assert\NotBlank(groups: ["stock:read","stock:write"])]
  private float $shippingFees = 0;
```

So `Assert\NotBlank` will only apply to `"stock:read","stock:write"` groups. I hope this helps you)